# Struggling to make client automatically receive a server's update

Tags: java

SOLVED: Was able to test it out earlier than I thought. Turns out my server side code was right and I wasn't checking a change in a variable on the client side constantly. Works perfectly now.

I'm working on a side project where I'm using the server to communicate with the client. Whenever the java server sends an update to the android client, it works on the first run. After that, the client doesn't register the server's message because when it worked on the first run, I already closed the socket so I tried a different approach.

I tried to just `flush()` the data through and only close it when I'm done reading data, but even with that `flush()` doesn't work unless I actually. My end goal is to send data through the server and to immediately show that data on the client side once I send it through. I'm just confused on how I can continuously send data from the server to the client without closing the socket or the stream (I'm using an OutputStreamWriter if that matters).

Edit: I forgot to mention but I do realize that flush() does actually send the data to the client, it just doesn't update the data on the client's UI until I close the stream. I'm trying to get it to update automatically

I can't post my code right now because I will not have access to it for a few hours. Some things I've tried are setTcpNoDelay to true and sending & receiving it through a byte stream, but this didn't work. Below is some pseudocode that can give you an idea of what the client and the server look like.

Server:

```
Open the server socket and make the client socket accept the server socket

While the user doesnt quit... 
     Enter a value to send to the client and
     try
        sendData(). After that,
close the outputstreamwriter

sendData(String data) - 
     Declare an outputstreamwriter(Calling it out)
     out.write(data)
     out.flush()
```

Client:

```
BufferedReader takes an InputStreamReader parameter and gets the socket's inputStream

While the bufferedReader hasNext
     String message = bufferedReader's input then 
     Display the data

bufferedReader.close()
```

Edit: From doing some research, does the data not send immediately because it's being buffered? If that is right, is there a way to speed up that process?(Sorry if that sounds stupid)

Answer (score 0):

I think a better option is to implement the protocol the opposite way.  That is, make the client inquiry the server for updates within a timer task, instead of pushing updates from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fundamental question, so you are by far not unique with this problem. Basically Server can not initiate communication with the client. Server serves the requests from client(s) and can not initiate the communication. In many cases Server doesn't know nor care about how many clients will he serve. On the other hand synchronous communication implies that the request-responce cycle should be short, I.e. you don't want to keep request connection opened for a long time or indefinitely. So there are many different approaches on how to make server to start talking to the client.

- The simplest one is "polling" i.e. client sends a requests to a server with pre-defined time period i.e. every 10 seconds, 3 hours or whatever fits your neeeds. This is simplistic solution that in many cases won't be sufficient but in some it is enough
- The other option is assynchronous communication where the client sends initial request and server sends the acknowledgement i.e. it says I got your request and will get back to you when I will have the answer. The client then will start listening on predefined queue. The server then once it has the answer will publish the answer in the queue and the client will consume it.

Those 2 are the most common solutions but not te only ones.